# jquery onclick within the parent

Tags: jquery, html

To simplify things, I have 2 ul list like below:

```
<ul class='same'>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul class='same'>
    <li>q</li>
    <li>w</li>
</ul>
```

As Im doing a custom slideshow, I am adding/removing class on li within that ul. However, doing this way of selector will of course selector all ul li

```
$("ul li")
```

I have 4 arrow with represent left,right,up down

```
    in another div**
<div class="arrow">
    <a>left</a>
    <a>right</a>
    <a>up</a>
    <a>down</a>
</div>
```

As you can imagine, slideshows are showed as grid. First ul represents first slider, the second slider represents second slider when clicked down arrow and so on and so fore.

[image: Demo of slideshow]

How can I target one ul li at a time without modifying css class?

Comment: do you have any javascript that you have tried

Comment: when are you doing ti... on click of an li

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axhwfbp9/1/

Comment: will you be able to edit the above fiddle to recreate your case..

Comment: where is the `arrow-right` element is it present in each `li`...

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think I kinda get where you are going for. The arrow right is in another div....

Comment: @ArunPJohny how can I disable the previous ul color red in your example?

Comment: can you share a better example... which will show the relationship betweent he arrow ans the ulr

Comment: what do you mean by disable...

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm getting what you are looking for...

Comment: @ArunPJohny sorry for the unclear meaning. as the jsfiddle you made, color is toggle by this ul li. If I click a new ul li, the old ul li is still red, how can i disable the old ul li?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axhwfbp9/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have put up a poorly mspaint for a better explanation :(  sorry english is not my native language

Comment: @ArunPJohny The concept is similar to mine, if you post it as an anwser i  will gladly will accept it :)

Comment: were you able to solve your problem with the concept

Comment: or whether http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axhwfbp9/3/ is a better example for you

Comment: @ArunPJohny your example is great, I will try to twist and put it in my codes. Thanks for your contribution! I usually deal everything with css/php and avoid using jquery. so,  I am a newbie in jquery, this has struggled me for 2 hours...im going to get killed....lol

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axhwfbp9/4/

Comment: so what is the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am looking for a way to traversal DOM, but didnt know jquery function well... You have done well for me, the 4 edition is what I needed, all its left is traversal in the li part. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OPs questions and the clarifications given OP want to know the currently active element and remove some attributes from the previous items

```
var $uls = $('ul.same');
$(".arrow a").click(function () {
    var $c = $uls.filter('.active').removeClass('active');
    var $n = $c.next();
    $n.addClass('active')

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/axhwfbp9/)